# Python: How to Extract Values from a Dictionary into A List --> Currently Getting dict_values() In Result

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

Let's say I have a dictionary below:

```
dict_test1 = {33: 114, 32: 14}
```

I want to extract out the values into a list.  Desired output:

```
[114, 14]
```

My code below is returning: dict_values([114, 14]) which is not what I want

```
dict_test1 = {33: 114, 32: 14}

a = dict_test1.values()
print (a)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can explicitly type-cast it to list by: `list(dict_test1.values())`

Comment: `print(list(a))`

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it into a list:

`print(list(a))`